# Is there any benefit to separate varchar(2xx) column from mysql table to nosql storage

Tags: mysql, nosql

If the numbers of the record is very big like N*10 M per table , is there any benefit to move the varchar(2xx) column to a nosql storage?  The content of the text won't be very long, I　think 200 characters is big enough. And the engine of mysql will be innoDB. The column won't be used as an index.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a specific column won't help performance much and will likely reduce performance because you need to get data from two places instead of one.

In general the slow part of any query is finding the right record - once you find that record, reading a few hundred bytes more doesn't really change anything.

Also, 10 million records of 200 characters is at most 4GB - not much even if your dataset needs to fit in RAM.